# Remove file permission in scheduled task windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a little problem in running a scheduled task on windows server 2012 R2. I have a task that executes a power shell script that backup a folder inside another location and should delete files older than 30 days in this second place (a NAS). The script works fine when I open an instance of power shell and launch it manually, but when I try to launch it from the task scheduler tool it blocks on the section relative to the elimination of older files.

I have work around permission in task maneger, checking the execute of the task with elevate privileges and also execute when the user is not logged in, but nothing works.

Here the script blocks:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-ChildItem $destination | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

I think that the problem could be find in some sort of missing permission for the user that execute the task, but I run it also with administrator user privileges but the problem is still present. Anyone have a suggestion about what to do to solve this problem? Is there any restriction in executing deleting operation in task scheduler? In case how can I enable this only for administrator profile?

Comment: Permissions were my first thought as well.  One thing to be careful of is how the user has permisions.  If the user running the task has permissions only due to being an administrator and UAC is enabled on the system, the session will have to be elevated in order for those permissions to take effect.  I've been bitten by this many times in the past.  A user with only Administrator privs on a file and running in a non-elevated process has NO ACCESS.  Be sure to explicitly grant permissions to the account used in Task Scheduler rather than rely on Administrator privs.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I still have a little doubt. In task scheduler I specify the user to use while running the task, that is administrator. Is this one the user you mention in the previous comment? Or I should search for a user that is the base executor of task scheduler if exists one? Sorry I'm not an expert.  - @Matthew